# how to use ace editor to make a html and css live preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ace-editor

i am very new to coding so please be gentle. i have been given a project by a college that i am studying at. to build an online interactive tutorial, very much in the same vane as codecademy and the like. the problem is i do not have very much experience with javascript or jquery, as i have not been taught them yet. at the end of the project what they want is an online interactive tutorial with a live preview of the html and the css. the problem is i have no idea how to go about doing all this without any help this is why i am here.

i have been doing quite a bit of research and have found a couple of very good prospects for helping me to achieve this. they are ace editor and codemirror the problem is there are no tutorials that i can find to help me.

i have been able to get the html working with a live preview but not css. here is my jquery code.

```
//initializing ace editor
var htmleditor = ace.edit("htmleditor");
htmleditor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
htmleditor.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");

var csseditor = ace.edit("csseditor");
csseditor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
csseditor.session.setMode("ace/mode/css");
//html editor
function showHTML() {
    $('#return').html(htmleditor.getValue());
}

function showHTMLInIFrame() {
    $('#return').html("<iframe src=" + "data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(htmleditor.getValue()) + "></iframe>");
}
htmleditor.on("input", showHTMLInIFrame);

//css editor
function showCss() {
    $('#return').css(csseditor.getValue());
}

function showCssInIFrame() {
    $('#return').css("<iframe src=" + "data:text/css," + encodeURIComponent(csseditor.getValue()) + "></iframe>");
}
csseditor.on("input", showCssInIFrame);
```

i have all the required js files attatched to my html. any help would be very much appreciated, even if you are just pointing me in the right direction. though if anyone can come up with a solution to the problem i am faced with, please let me know.

regards

Phil

Answer (score 0):

Structure your logic such that you have two ACE editors (which you have done), and a single `iframe` you will be updating. Combine the results from your HTML editor with the results from your CSS editor and assign them to the single iframe.

Create your iframe ahead of time, and give it an id value.

```
<iframe id="return"></iframe>

function updateIframe() {
  var html = htmleditor.getValue()  
  var css = htmleditor.getValue()

  $('#return').srcdoc = html + css
}

htmleditor.on("input", updateIframe);
csseditor.on("input", updateIframe);
```